# which will be executed first in a short-circuit evaluation (a&&b)

Tags: c

Lets say I have the following code:

```
if (a&&b)
{
...
}
```

First question, who decides to use short-circuit evaluation in this circumstance? the compiler or the C standard?

Second question, which one will be evaluated first? `a` or `b`. The sequence is decided by whom and is there way to change the sequence in my code?

Comment: In C short-circuiting of logical expressions is guaranteed has always been a feature of C. It was true when Dennis Ritchie designed and implemented the first version of C, still true in the 1989 C standard, and remains true in the C99 standard.

Answer (score 7):

1. Short-circuit evaluation is required by the standard.
2. It's always `a` first. You can't change that in your program.

Reference: **6.5.13 Logical AND operator**, paragraph 4:

> Unlike the bitwise binary **`&`** operator, the **`&&`** operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second operands. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.